# how prevent postfix from adding received header

Tags: postfix-mta

We are wanting to use Postfix as a relay. Is there a way to prevent it from adding a received header when receiving mail from any internal or external host?

Comment: I am having this problem too on the [advanced filter](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#receive_override_options). Postfix adds 3 `Received` headers for every filtered mail.